# Upload File to SharePoint through VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, fso

I've been seeing this code (or similar to this) in some forums but some do not have this lines for mapping:  "objNet.MapNetworkDrive “A: ” , SharepointAddress"

Is it safe for the computer/network to omit this code?

```
Sub UploadToSharepoint()

Dim SharepointAddress As String
 Dim LocalAddress As String
 Dim objNet As Object
 Dim FS As Object
 SharepointAddress = "http://share.deere.com/teams/sm_at_sd/suppcaptracking/Test"

 LocalAddress = "c: MyWorkFiletoCopy.xlsx"

Set objNet = CreateObject(“WScript.Network”)

Set FS = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
 objNet.MapNetworkDrive “A: ” , SharepointAddress

If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
 FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
 End If

objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive “A: ”

Set objNet = Nothing

Set FS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a better approach:

```
Sub UploadToSharepoint()

    Dim SharepointAddress As String
    Dim LocalAddress As String
    Dim FS As Object

    SharepointAddress = "\\share.deere.com\teams\sm_at_sd\uppcaptracking\Test"

    LocalAddress = "c:\blah\blah2\MyWorkFiletoCopy.xlsx"

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
        FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
    End If

End Sub
```

Should not need to map a drive.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Will it not cause harm to the memory or to anything?