# Upload file to document folder in sharepoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, runtime-error, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create the file and then upload it directly to the SharePoint folder using VBA.

Have tried this code -

```
    Sub UploadToSharepoint()

    Dim SharepointAddress As String
    Dim LocalAddress As String
    Dim FS As Object

    SharepointAddress = "\\blah.sharepoint.com\sites\test_vba_sharepoint\Shared%20Documents\Forms\AllItems.aspx"

    LocalAddress = "C:\blah1\blah\Desktop\blah3\output.xlsx"

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress

     End Sub
```

Have also added the website URL to my trusted sites in Internet Explorer.

[image]

still, it shows me the error -
[image]

[image]

Please let me know if we have any solution.

reference - [Upload File to SharePoint through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439294/upload-file-to-sharepoint-through-vba)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [excel vba to upload file to sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510770/excel-vba-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint)

Comment: Nope, That's why I report the same. Please let me know if I have missed any!

Comment: Your sharepoint address is all wrong. Check out the way its entered on the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50510770/7446760

Comment: I have the SharePoint document as a https://commencellc.sharepoint.com and I have added the same to internet explorer. Also i need to upload the file from the "C:\ouput.xlsx" to the https://commencellc.sharepoint.com/sites/test_vba_sharepoint/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx pelase let me know what I missed here @CLR

Comment: Based on the answer I linked above, you'd need to change it to something like `"\\commencellc.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\test_vba_sharepoint\Shared Documents"` and ensure WebClient service is running.

Comment: Still it is showing me the error 2147024672 (800700e0) - Automation Error.

Comment: Just to let you know - that my SharePoint site has MFA enabled, which means it requires an OTP before logging in. Is there a possibility that this might affect the VBA code?

Comment: Can you open the page in Internet Explorer and then click 'Open in File explorer' - to get the full path. If it needs MFA, I imagine that would cause an issue though.