# Uploading files to a specific SharePoint folder

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

My question is on MS Access VBA and SharePoint. I have an Access database which I use for generating timesheets. However, things have changed lately and now the expectation is that I upload them to SharePoint. I have created a folder in the documents library called Timesheets. Is this correct? If so, how to I upload a file in a button click? If this is successful,
can I share the URL link to users with read privilege to view the file?

Please see below my attempt to solve the problem:

```
Sub SharePointUploader_Click()

    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3


Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected."
    Else
        selectedFile = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If
End With
    destinationFolderURL = "https://mysite365.sharepoint.com/sites/Science-Department/Documents/Timesheets/"
    webDAVURL = destinationFolderURL & Replace(Mid(selectedFile, InStrRev(selectedFile, "\") + 1), " ", "%20")

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    fs.CopyFile selectedFile, webDAVURL

    Set fd = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

    MsgBox "File uploaded to SharePoint!", vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439294/upload-file-to-sharepoint-through-vba and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-save-workbook-to-sharepoint/5eca44d1-a94e-4b28-ba20-fa3ae661af80

Comment: Sync the folder to your local PC, and save the files to the local copy of the folder.

Comment: @June7 my main problem is figuring out what the 'SharepointAddress' is as from the link you sent. Then there is also a problem of constructing a URL link that opens the file if the link is shared withs others. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have never used SharePoint so cannot offer any guidance other than what I already attempted.